# Disk mirroring over USB on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive

I'm reading a ton of contradictory information about whether Windows supports mirroring for USB drives, if I have to use dynamic drives and/or storage spaces.  Can anyone here clarify the matter?

I have a new 14TB USB drive connected over USB 3.1 Gen 2.  As I have no faith in that not developing bit rot and/or bad sectors I'd like to put it in a RAID 1 with another.

Windows 10 seems to have a feature that allows one to specify a new disk to mirror to, but some sources are saying this requires it to be configured as a dynamic disk, others that this doesn't work on USB.

Can anyone here shed some light on the true situation before I invest in a new drive and docking station?

Answer (score 1):

It definitely used to be the case that you could not mirror over USB.  However, Windows Storage Spaces has rectified that problem.  There are several guides out there on how to do it.  Here are two:

- https://www.howtogeek.com/109380/how-to-use-windows-8s-storage-spaces-to-mirror-combine-drives/
- [https://www.peterviola.com/easy-usb-drive-mirroring-with-windows-10-storage-spaces/#:~:text=Fortunately%20Windows%2010%20Storage%20Spaces,two%20external%20USB%20hard%20drives](https://www.peterviola.com/easy-usb-drive-mirroring-with-windows-10-storage-spaces/#:%7E:text=Fortunately%20Windows%2010%20Storage%20Spaces,two%20external%20USB%20hard%20drives).